# Inserting value in column from other table

Tags: oracle, insert

```
col1     col2     col3      col4
          34       56
          12       67
          34       43
          41       12
```

now I'm inserting values in col1 from other table column col1

```
col1     col2     col3      col4
          34       56
          12       67
          34       43
          41       12
23
67
89
90
```

values in col1 are inserting like this...is there any way by which I can
insert the data as

```
col1     col2     col3      col4

23        34       56
67        12       67
89        34       43
90        41       12
```

Comment: This might be an sql question. Then again, it might not. Please add some more tag(s) (if it's SQL, please specify what database system as a separate tag). Now, onto the specifics - By what reason is `23` associated with the row with (col2,col3) = (34,56), and not any of the other rows? Please state a clear rule for this.

Comment: You are talking about any rdbms or html tables ?

Comment: no reason,i m just told to do this..srchd the net bt couldn't find anythng.......i m talking abt rdbms table

Comment: Technically, the answer is *no*. You can't "insert" into existing rows, you must *update* them.

Comment: okiee..den what is the way by which i can solve the above question using update?